# Prove: For every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a $\delta >0$ such that $1 - \delta < x < 1 + \delta$ implies that $2 - \epsilon < 7 -5x< 2 + \epsilon$

Tags: proof-verification

So far this is what I have

Let
$$
\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{5}
$$

So, if we start with $1 - \delta < x < 1 + \delta$

\begin{align}
                   &\Rightarrow -5 + 5\delta < -5x < -5 -5\delta \quad \text{(multiply by} -5) \\
                   &\Rightarrow 2 + 5\delta < 7 -5x < 2 - 5\delta \quad \text{(add} \,\, 7) \\
                   &\Rightarrow 2 + 5 * \frac{\epsilon}{5} < 7 - 5x < 2 - 5*5\epsilon \quad \text{(substitute)}\\
                  &\Rightarrow 2 + \epsilon < 7 - 5x < 2 - \epsilon \quad \text{(simplify)}
\end{align}

Is there something about inequalities that I am forgetting that my signs are opposite or am I doing something completely wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

When you multiply an inequality by a negative number, the direction of the inequality is reversed, so that

$$
1-\delta < x < 1+\delta
$$

implies

$$
-5+5\delta > -5x > -5-5\delta
$$

Answer (score 0):

When you multiply two sides of an inequality by a negative number, the direction of inequality is reversed.

Example, 1 < 2, 
Multiplying by -5 yields -5 > -10 and not -5 < -10